# Assigning C String to a member of a struct through an array of pointers in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am getting the error "error C2106: '=' : left operand must be l-value" and I cannot figure out how to fix this.

Here is my structure definition:

```
 typedef struct{
    int temperature;
    char city[100];
    }City;
```

Here is where I am getting the error:

```
    ptrAvgTemps[0]->city = ptrArray[0]->city;
```

ptrAvgTemps is an array of pointers to empty City's and ptrArray is another array of pointers to City's and has the data I need to put into the other array.
(I'm trying to average out the City's temperature and just copy over the city string.)

Here is my function header.

```
void getAverageTemperatures(City** ptrArray, City** ptrAvgTemps, int numberOfLines, int* numOfCities)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: dammit,    sorry it's my second week in a class learning C after learning C++.  Thanks user

Comment: In addition to what user3386109 said, raw arrays can't be assigned.

Comment: @Kris lol, you've been spoiled by C++. C is closer to the bare metal, so I expect you'll be having lots of fun like this :)